# Bootstrap navbar not dropping down

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-5

Plain navbar from bootstrap 5 docs is used.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">¿qué es?</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Acciones subvencionables</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Nuestro equipo</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contacta con nosotros</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Recursos y más información</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Bootstram.min.css at top of page. No extra css used, and jquery is placed at the bottom of my page.
There are no console errors.
By the way, using laravel.
I cant seem to find any reason for not dropping down/collapse my hamburger.
Thanks in advance

Comment: btw already tried to clear cache and views with artisan

Answer (score -1):

Sorry if anyone got on research it was a dumb error.

bootstrap css was placed prior to styles.css
Thanks anyway